# How to center a handsontable properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, handsontable

I am using handsontable and I would like to show a table centered in the page or a div.

I have managed to do this by changing the width of the container div after the table is initiated (see snippet). However this seems cumbersome.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var container = document.getElementById('basic_example');
  
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10, 12),
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    afterInit: function () {
      $("#basic_example").css("width", $("#basic_example .wtHider").css("width")) 
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
#basic_example {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://handsontable.com//styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://handsontable.com//bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://handsontable.com//bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>

<div id="basic_example"></div>
```

Is there an easy/better way of centering a handsontable?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9kJB3/2/   check if that helps!!

Comment: That looks ok but I has the side effect of centering the text inside the cells.

Comment: Notice as well that his provokes weird effects with dropdowns http://jsfiddle.net/o4xayoLn/1/

Comment: I would definitely go with the auto margins. Do you have a way to know the width of the parent div before initializing the handson component? If you don't and you're trying to center it based on what with happens to be after it's initialized, then your solution is pretty damn good. If you do know what the width of your div will be, then just set the width of the handson div to 100% and set the parent div to whatever you want.

Comment: I don't know the width beforehand as the data is variable. I guess I'll have to stick to the `afterInit`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your work-around, I would recommend using afterRender instead of afterInit in order to update the size of your table whenever the handsontable is rendered.

This would be especially useful if the user changes the size of the screen, if you allow the addition of columns or rows, or if there are other possibilities of the table changing sizes after the original initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the earlier answers, I used the afterRender (and afterChange) events as follows:

```
  afterRender: function () {
    let wtHider = document.querySelector('#tableContainer .wtHider');
    container.style.width = wtHider.style.width
  },
```

However, when you hide a column, it seems that afterRender is fired too early, before the element with the wtHider class is updated.

Adding a delay of 0 ms solves this issue:

```
   afterRender: function () {
    let wtHider = document.querySelector('#tableContainer .wtHider');
    setTimeout(() => {
      container.style.width = wtHider.style.width
    }, 0);
  },
```

Note: Tested using chromium version 87.0.4280.66, Ubuntu 20.04 and handsontable 8.2.0